# Android - Crash on generating random number

Tags: java, android, random, runtime-error

So, I have looked at other places for how to generate a random number, and put it into an Android app. I would expect this to work, but sadly, it crashes with this LogCat:

```
11-03 17:06:48.930: W/dalvikvm(8327): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ff0300)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:187)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at com.spng453.randomnum.RandomNumber$1.onClick(RandomNumber.java:24)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-03 17:06:48.938: E/AndroidRuntime(8327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 17:06:51.376: I/Process(8327): Sending signal. PID: 8327 SIG: 9
```

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work, but nothing does. Here's the code:

```
private OnClickListener Gen = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random rand;
        rand = new Random();
        EditText maxin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.max);
        EditText minin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.min);
        TextView out = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);
        int max = Integer.parseInt(maxin.getText().toString().trim());
        int min = Integer.parseInt(minin.getText().toString().trim());
        out.setText(Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(max-min) + min));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that will certainly happen if your `max` text box has a number smaller than or equal to your `min` text box. You should validate that before calling [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29). As the docs state:

> **Throws:**
>   IllegalArgumentException - if n is not positive

Of course you should *also* handle the situation where your text boxes don't have a valid number in at all.

Finally, is there any reason *why* you're separating the declaration and assignment of `rand`?

```
Random rand;
rand = new Random();
```

Why not just:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

?

Comment: Ok, I'll look at that. Thanks! EDIT: THANKS! I didn't realize, but I got the two text boxes switched. I end up doing stupid mistakes like that all the time.

Comment: Also, I didn't just to Random rand = new Random(); because I thought that might be the problem. Lastly, the textboxes are the number only textboxes, and if I were to figure out a way to input letters, then I would add a letter checking thing.

Comment: @spng453: How could the declaration possibly have been the problem? It sounds like you need to take more of a step back and really look at the error message and stack trace when something falls over. Also, if the textboxes only admit digits, why are you trimming the string? And what happens if the user enters a number which can't be stored in an `int`?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. If they put in a decimal, it will still error. And also, I knew that the error was not that, but I was just trying everything just in case, I just forgot to put it back like it should be. Also, for the trim, I was just used to working with textboxes with strings, kinda a habit and I didn't realize.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` indicates that you're passing an illegal argument to you `nextInt()` function.  I'm guessing that your argument is less zero, or something similar to that.  Check those values in the debugger to make sure your arguments are valid.